# Can I use variables somehow with .on Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, click

I have 3 buttons inside one div and I want to add the same click listener to all of them. I have a few actions on those buttons so I first keep them as variables in the begging of the function and then I want to add the on listener, using those variables. Is there any way?
The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="a"></button>
    <button class="b"></button>
    <button class="c"></button>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper'),
    $aBtn = $wrapper.find('.a'),
    $bBtn = $wrapper.find('.b'),
    $cBtn = $wrapper.find('.c');

//The working but less neat solution
$('.wrapper .a, .wrapper .b, .wrapper .c').on('click', func);

//What I want
($aBtn, $bBtn, $cBtn).on('click', func);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.add()` // [Ref link](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper'),
    $aBtn = $wrapper.find('.a'),
    $bBtn = $wrapper.find('.b'),
    $cBtn = $wrapper.find('.c');

//What I want
$($aBtn).add($bBtn).add($cBtn).on('click', func);

function func(){alert($(this).attr("class"))}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="a">a</button>
    <button class="b">b</button>
    <button class="c">c</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: `add` accepts multiple arguments, and no need for `$()` at the beginning (`add` returns a new object, it doesn't modify what it's called on): `$aBtn.add($bBtn).add($cBtn).on(...)`

Comment: Very true, just an old habit :)

Answer (score 1):

Using add function

```
$aBtn.add($bBtn,$cBtn).on('click', func);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code doesn't use variables, but you can sometimes simply bind events on selectors that wraps multiple elements

```
$('.wrapper button').on('click', func);
```

With this code, each button has an event handler attached to it.
When you click an element, *this* reference the element like showcased in this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3uwx15vg/1/

As an alternative to variables, you can even chain event handlers

```
$('.wrapper button').on('click', func).on('blur', func);
```

Comment: It might be a good solution for the specific problem I described but if you have more buttons under wrapper which you don't want a listener attach to them you have to specify a new class to those you do. but I get your point overall.

Comment: @LilacEilim : indeed. I usually attach my handlers to elements with specific data-* attributes (and rarely with specific classes prefix with js-*)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $wrapper = $('.wrapper'),
  $aBtn = ('.wrapper .a '),
  $bBtn = ('.wrapper .b '),
  $cBtn = ('.wrapper .c ');

//The working but less neat solution
//$('.wrapper .a, .wrapper .b, .wrapper .c').on('click', func);

//What I want
$($aBtn+", "+$bBtn+", "+$cBtn).on('click', func);

function func() {
  alert($(this).text())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="a">1</button>
  <button class="b">2</button>
  <button class="c">3</button>
</div>
```

If you can change the selector just concat them as you would with `'.wrapper .a, .wrapper .b, .wrapper .c'`